# Android AlertDialog not showing radio buttons or message

Tags: android, radio-button, android-alertdialog

In my app I bring up a context menu on long click in a ListActivity.  One of the options "Priority" pops up an AlertDialog with 3 radio button choices.  The problem is, it displays an empty dialog box without my 3 choices, or the message that I set.  Here is my code..

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    AlertDialog dialog;
    switch(id) {
    case DIALOG_SAB_PRIORITY_ID:
        final CharSequence[] items = {"High", "Normal", "Low"};

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SabMgmt.this);
        builder.setMessage("Select new priority")
               .setSingleChoiceItems(items, 0, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), items[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        dialog = builder.create();            
        break;
    default:
        dialog = null;
    }
    return dialog;
}
```

If I replace the .setSingleChoiceItems with a positive and negative button instead, it displays the buttons and the message as expected.  What am I doing wrong in setting up my list of radio buttons?  Here is my calling code as well..

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.sabdelete:
        // Correct position (-1) for 1 header
        final SabQueueItem qItem = (SabQueueItem) itla.getItem(info.position-1);
        SabNZBdUtils.deleteItem(qItem.getNzo_id());
        getQueue();
        ListView lv = getListView();
        View v = lv.findViewById(R.id.sablistheader);
        setHeader(v);
        itla.notifyDataSetChanged();
        return true;
    case R.id.sabpriority:
        showDialog(DIALOG_SAB_PRIORITY_ID);
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Figured it out!  I was using builder.setMessage on a singleChoiceItem dialog instead of builder.setTitle.  It seems that dialogs using radio button choices don't support setting a message, only a title.  Seems strange that the method is provided though.  Anyhow, here is the working code..

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    AlertDialog dialog;
    switch(id) {
    case DIALOG_SAB_PRIORITY_ID:
        final CharSequence[] items = {"High", "Normal", "Low"};

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SabMgmt.this);
        builder.setTitle("Select new priority")
               .setSingleChoiceItems(items, 0, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), items[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        dialog = builder.create();  
        break;
    default:
        dialog = null;
    }
    return dialog;
```

Comment: Thank you! I just banged my head against the wall for an hour trying to figure out why my alert dialog kept coming up empty.

Comment: Thanks a lot. this is crazy. and this could be documented somewhere.

Comment: Tanks! I got crazy searching for this bug!

Comment: It's not a bug it's a feature ;) And i agree it isn't that nice that i understand why not

Comment: Thankyou so much for ur help , thankyou for sharing your knowledge. how did you guessed that